# Searching for a file in a Git branch

Tags: git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I'm trying to get the functionality to search for a file in all branches. For example, I have 10 branches and I need to get all different version of that file (to look it, compare or more, for example I could have many personalized documents for clients, `.css` files,  source files with something hardcoded - it's not important - I just have to have access to all of this). It is possible with libgit2sharp library? Or other libgit2 implementation?

I know about this

```
public BranchCollection Branches{
    get { return branches; }
}
```

and this route

```
string pathToRepo = "directory//folders//.git";
using (var repo = new Repository(pathToRepo))
{
    foreach (var branch in repo.Branches)
    {
        var file = branch.SEARCH_FOR_FILE(string fileName); //I need something like this   
        Console.WriteLine("File found in" + branch.Name + "yours stuff: " + file.ToString()/something other);
    }
}
```

I found code and examples which provides searching for specified commits in logs, adding/moving/deleting branches, but... nothing about searching for a file. Someone can help me? It is possible in sensible time at all? If I'm using Git, I can try search, like brute force in the file system for a file in all branches-folders (but it is a bad idea I guess) and what if I want to implement database backend?

If I am right, something similar is implemented in Git, with the command:

```
git log --all --pretty=format: | sort -u | grep MyAwesomeFile.extension
```

Comment: To get all commits concerning a file, `git log --follow filename` is what you should use, optionally add `--pretty=format:"%h"`before the filename if you want just the hash. That's if you stick to native git...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Git, each commit contains a whole snapshot of the source code. Besides, each commit, contains a pointer to its parent(s) commit(s) (i.e. previous version of the snapshot). This child to parent relationship allows one to walk along the chain and compare the different versions in order to detect the changes along this chain of commits.

A branch points to only one commit (i.e. the "latest" version).

As such, the same file (e.g.: `/path/to/my/file.css`) may exist in different shapes in the tip of the branch (the latest commit) or its ancestors.

From your question, I understand that you're willing to extract from the tip of all your branches the same file in order to compare them against one another.

This can be easily done with LibGit2Sharp. The `Commit` exposes an indexer which accepts a path. This will return a `TreeEntry`. The `Target` property points to the `GitObject` (a `Blob` in this case, as you're after a file rather than a directory).

The code below will enumerate all branches and dump the content of each file named `/path/to/my/file.css`. Warning, the code below assumes that the file indeed exists in all your branches, you may have to tweak it a little bit wouldn't this be the case.

```
foreach (var branch in repo.Branches)
{
    var treeEntry = branch.Tip["/path./to/my/file.css"];

    if (treeEntry == null)
    {
         // The file doesn't exist in this commit
         continue;
    }

    var blob = (Blob)treeEntry.Target;
    Console.WriteLine(blob.GetContentAsText());
}
```

Comment: If this doesn't completely answer your question, please refine it, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, this solutions should fits very well to my task! I have few answers anyway!

1) The path 

`Tip["/path./to/my/file.css"] `

is always relative path from main folder of branch in which we are searching? And using pointers, library don't have to do something like costly switching branches, right?

Comment: 2) If I would use similliar solution when I have file "example.css" just in 80-90% branches, it is impossible, yes? I can't catch an exception of NullReference, ignore that branch and go on (except magic spell called goto :P). I must have empty "example.css" file in that 10-20% files?

3) It is not directly related but I don't get it at all - using blobs and trees - they are using Git repository too, but in other way? It's mapping file -> BLOB, path and dependencies, pointers -> tree? And this method provides me utility to have a database backend?

Comment: @Izzy 1a) The path is relative to the root of your commit. 1b) No branch switching is required 2) I've updated the code to show how to avoid the NullPointerException 3) This looks like a different topic. Maybe a good fit for another StackOverflow question ;)